# Exchanging data between sibling components in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a parent component in angular 2 with two children which are siblings.
Sibling1 has a button, Sibling2 has simply a h1 element that should change its text when the button in Sibling1 is pressed. I've heard that the best way to do this is to use a shared service. However I can't figure it out. The text is not changed upon button press.

### Parent

imports SharedService and has it as provider

template:

```
<sibling1></sibling1>
<sibling2></sibling2>
```

### SharedService

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';

private text = new Subject<string>();
text$ = this.text.asObservable();

publishText(textToPublish: string){
    this.text.next(textToPublish);
}
```

### Sibling1

```
import {SharedService} from './shared.service';

<button (click)="onClick()">press me</button>    

export class Sibling1{

    constructor(private ss: SharedService){}

    onClick(){
        this.ss.publishText('sample text');
    }

}
```

### Sibling2

```
import {SharedService} from './shared.service';

<h1>{{text}}</h1>

export class Sibling2{

    text: string;

    constructor(private ss: SharedService){
        ss.text$.subscribe(data => this.text = data);
    }
 }
```

### Module

imports ParentComponent, Sibling1, Sibling2 and SharedService

and has declarations: ParentComponent, Sibling1, Sibling2

and providers: [SharedService]

I am also unsure about which imports and providers I need to declare in the app module and the parent component. Thank you.

Comment: You are on the right track by starting with a share service. Also, look into the EventEmitter (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/EventEmitter-class.html). More info: (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html)

Comment: Can you create plnkr?

Comment: you have not `providers: [SharedService]` in your components, right, only in the module? :)

Comment: @AJT_82: i do, edited my OP

Comment: See my answer below with a plknr that should fix your issue.

Comment: can i get data without click? with above example, what i need to change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a plknr that should help you. Have a look at http://plnkr.co/edit/60ncOxHwiOy8biiUc9mt?p=info

As AJT_82 said, you probably forgot to add the `providers: [SharedService]`

**Update**

I updated the plunker in order to use `ngOnInit` to get the subscription and `ngOnDestroy` in order to unsubscribe from it when the component is destroyed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to make this and help me! I'm curious why the module knows what SharedService is without importing it though. And is it better to import SharedService in the app component or import it in the module and add it to providers there?

Comment: @onTheFence, just a tips, you don't need the `.asObservable` in your service. Your components can subscribe straight to the `subject`

Comment: Hi, I would still advice to use the `asObservable`. It is indeed possible to subscribe to the `Subject` but the risk is that the subscriber could also emit data on this `Subject` and it's rarely what the developer wanted. Using `asObservable` ensure that a subscriber can only receive data from it.

Comment: @ssougnez, sure, that is true!

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your problem correctly I'd go with observables. Create an observable in the service subscribe in sibling 2 and change whatever you need with the sibling 1.

This may be of some help: http://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-build-angular2-apps-using-rxjs-observable-data-services-pitfalls-to-avoid/

Comment: that's exactly what i am tying to do